# Predicting answers from data in a CSV file when user asks a question

Tags: neural-network, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

I have a CSV file with columns on crop production
[Columns of the CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeOZp.jpg)
If a user asks a question like
What should I produce in Maharashtra in 2019? 
User should get an answer based on the history of the data in CSV
Can someone help me with the implementation?

Comment: There are a great project, it's rank fourth in kaggle Quora Question.
https://github.com/HouJP/kaggle-quora-question-pairs

Answer (score 0):

For a good answer (training), you probably need the amount of requested or sold crop rather than the amount of produced crop.

A first implementation could give the average of the past years production. Possibly weighing the past few years more.

Comment: Got it Thanks a lot